# XSLT Muenchian grouping from BizTalk WCF-SQL Adapter Schema by ID across groups

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, biztalk, xslt-grouping, biztalk-mapper

I am working on a BizTalk application that performs typed polling from a database using the WCF SQL adapter. After researching how to group data from the generated schema to my canonical schema, I came across [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) as the common solution. However, I am having a hard time figure out how to  apply it to my situation.

Basically, the data that I am polling is spread out across multiple tables which are a mix of one-to-one and one-to-many relationships that share the same primary key across all the tables. Due to the one-to-many relationships, I cannot extract all of the data from the various tables using a single SELECT statement, and opted to instead split it up as [multiple queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37668583/biztalk-wcf-sql-adapter-how-to-receive-records-from-a-database-with-one-to-many) in my Polling Data statement which generated the source schema shown in the image below.

What I am trying to do is simply separate all of the records from my source schema by "SharedID" and put them into the appropriate record in my destination schema. (I also have secondary instance number ID's for subgroups, but I would imagine those will be solved in the same manner.) All of the examples I have seen show how to do this when the XSLT key is derived from a [single node](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chrisromp/2008/07/31/muenchian-grouping-and-sorting-in-biztalk-maps/) or [multiple nodes](http://mohitt-gupta.blogspot.com/2013/05/grouping-in-biztalk-map-based-on.html) from the source schema, but they don't show how to account for when the same ID is coming from multiple nodes.

I have analyzed the examples from many sources as best I can, but I am still new to XSLT so I am having a hard time figuring out how to set up my keys and for-each statements to accommodate this approach. Any help demystifying how I should go about doing this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Here is a screenshot of a map using generalized versions of my source and destination schema structure.

[image]

Here is the XSLT that the map above generates, which I am using as my starting point.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var s0"
                version="1.0"
                xmlns:s0="http://SmallGenericSchemaTest.Schemas/SourceSchema"
                xmlns:ns0="http://SmallGenericSchemaTest.Schemas/DestinationSchema">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/s0:TypedPolling" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/s0:TypedPolling">
        <ns0:AllRecords>
            <ns0:SingleRecord>
                <xsl:for-each select="s0:TypedPollingResultSet0">
                    <xsl:for-each select="s0:TypedPollingResultSet0">
                        <ns0:GroupA>
                            <xsl:if test="s0:SharedID">
                                <ns0:SharedID>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="s0:SharedID/text()" />
                                </ns0:SharedID>
                            </xsl:if>

                            <xsl:if test="s0:MiscInfoA1">
                                <ns0:MiscInfoA1>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="s0:MiscInfoA1/text()" />
                                </ns0:MiscInfoA1>
                            </xsl:if>

                            <xsl:if test="s0:MiscInfoA2">
                                <ns0:MiscInfoA2>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="s0:MiscInfoA2/text()" />
                                </ns0:MiscInfoA2>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </ns0:GroupA>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>

                <xsl:for-each select="s0:TypedPollingResultSet1">
                    <xsl:for-each select="s0:TypedPollingResultSet1">
                        <ns0:GroupB>
                            <xsl:if test="s0:MiscInfoB1">
                                <ns0:MiscInfoB1>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="s0:MiscInfoB1/text()" />
                                </ns0:MiscInfoB1>
                            </xsl:if>

                            <xsl:if test="s0:MiscInfoB2">
                                <ns0:MiscInfoB2>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="s0:MiscInfoB2/text()" />
                                </ns0:MiscInfoB2>
                            </xsl:if>

                            <ns0:SubGroupBAContainer>
                                <xsl:for-each select="../../s0:TypedPollingResultSet2">
                                    <xsl:for-each select="s0:TypedPollingResultSet2">
                                        <ns0:SubGroupBA>
                                            <xsl:if test="s0:MiscInfoBA1">
                                                <ns0:MiscInfoBA1>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="s0:MiscInfoBA1/text()" />
                                                </ns0:MiscInfoBA1>
                                            </xsl:if>

                                            <xsl:if test="s0:MiscInfoBA2">
                                                <ns0:MiscInfoBA2>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="s0:MiscInfoBA2/text()" />
                                                </ns0:MiscInfoBA2>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                        </ns0:SubGroupBA>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </ns0:SubGroupBAContainer>

                            <ns0:SubGroupBBContainer>
                                <xsl:for-each select="../../s0:TypedPollingResultSet3">
                                    <xsl:for-each select="s0:TypedPollingResultSet3">
                                        <ns0:SubGroupBB>
                                            <xsl:if test="s0:MiscInfoBB1">
                                                <ns0:MiscInfoBB1>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="s0:MiscInfoBB1/text()" />
                                                </ns0:MiscInfoBB1>
                                            </xsl:if>

                                            <xsl:if test="s0:MiscInfoBB2">
                                                <ns0:MiscInfoBB2>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="s0:MiscInfoBB2/text()" />
                                                </ns0:MiscInfoBB2>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                        </ns0:SubGroupBB>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </ns0:SubGroupBBContainer>
                        </ns0:GroupB>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>

                <ns0:GroupCContainer>
                    <xsl:for-each select="s0:TypedPollingResultSet4">
                        <xsl:for-each select="s0:TypedPollingResultSet4">
                            <ns0:GroupC>
                                <xsl:if test="s0:GroupCInstanceID">
                                    <ns0:GroupCInstanceID>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="s0:GroupCInstanceID/text()" />
                                    </ns0:GroupCInstanceID>
                                </xsl:if>

                                <xsl:if test="s0:MiscInfoC1">
                                    <ns0:MiscInfoC1>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="s0:MiscInfoC1/text()" />
                                    </ns0:MiscInfoC1>
                                </xsl:if>

                                <xsl:if test="s0:MiscInfoC2">
                                    <ns0:MiscInfoC2>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="s0:MiscInfoC2/text()" />
                                    </ns0:MiscInfoC2>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </ns0:GroupC>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </ns0:GroupCContainer>

                <ns0:GroupDContainer>
                    <xsl:for-each select="s0:TypedPollingResultSet5">
                        <xsl:for-each select="s0:TypedPollingResultSet5">
                            <ns0:GroupD>
                                <xsl:if test="s0:GroupDInstanceID">
                                    <ns0:GroupDInstanceID>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="s0:GroupDInstanceID/text()" />
                                    </ns0:GroupDInstanceID>
                                </xsl:if>

                                <xsl:if test="s0:MiscInfoD1">
                                    <ns0:MiscInfoD1>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="s0:MiscInfoD1/text()" />
                                    </ns0:MiscInfoD1>
                                </xsl:if>

                                <xsl:if test="s0:MiscInfoD2">
                                    <ns0:MiscInfoD2>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="s0:MiscInfoD2/text()" />
                                    </ns0:MiscInfoD2>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:for-each select="../../s0:TypedPollingResultSet6">
                                    <xsl:for-each select="s0:TypedPollingResultSet6">
                                        <ns0:SubGroupDA>
                                            <xsl:if test="s0:MiscInfoDA1">
                                                <ns0:MiscInfoDA1>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="s0:MiscInfoDA1/text()" />
                                                </ns0:MiscInfoDA1>
                                            </xsl:if>

                                            <xsl:if test="s0:MiscInfoDA2">
                                                <ns0:MiscInfoDA2>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="s0:MiscInfoDA2/text()" />
                                                </ns0:MiscInfoDA2>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                        </ns0:SubGroupDA>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </xsl:for-each>

                                <ns0:SubGroupDBContainer>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="../../s0:TypedPollingResultSet7">
                                        <xsl:for-each select="s0:TypedPollingResultSet7">
                                            <ns0:SubGroupDB>
                                                <xsl:if test="s0:MiscInfoDB1">
                                                    <ns0:MiscInfoDB1>
                                                        <xsl:value-of select="s0:MiscInfoDB1/text()" />
                                                    </ns0:MiscInfoDB1>
                                                </xsl:if>

                                                <xsl:if test="s0:MiscInfoDB2">
                                                    <ns0:MiscInfoDB2>
                                                        <xsl:value-of select="s0:MiscInfoDB2/text()" />
                                                    </ns0:MiscInfoDB2>
                                                </xsl:if>
                                            </ns0:SubGroupDB>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </ns0:SubGroupDBContainer>
                            </ns0:GroupD>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </ns0:GroupDContainer>
            </ns0:SingleRecord>
        </ns0:AllRecords>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**EDIT:**

Here is a sample input xml document and the desired output.

Sample input:

```
<ns0:TypedPolling xmlns:ns0="http://SmallGenericSchemaTest.Schemas/SourceSchema">
    <ns0:TypedPollingResultSet0>
        <ns0:TypedPollingResultSet0>
            <ns0:SharedID>SharedID_1</ns0:SharedID>
            <ns0:MiscInfoA1>A1_1</ns0:MiscInfoA1>
            <ns0:MiscInfoA2>A2_1</ns0:MiscInfoA2>
        </ns0:TypedPollingResultSet0>

        <ns0:TypedPollingResultSet0>
            <ns0:SharedID>SharedID_2</ns0:SharedID>
            <ns0:MiscInfoA1>A1_2</ns0:MiscInfoA1>
            <ns0:MiscInfoA2>A2_2</ns0:MiscInfoA2>
        </ns0:TypedPollingResultSet0>
    </ns0:TypedPollingResultSet0>

    <ns0:TypedPollingResultSet1>
        <ns0:TypedPollingResultSet1>
            <ns0:SharedID>SharedID_1</ns0:SharedID>
            <ns0:MiscInfoB1>B1_1</ns0:MiscInfoB1>
            <ns0:MiscInfoB2>B2_1</ns0:MiscInfoB2>
        </ns0:TypedPollingResultSet1>

        <ns0:TypedPollingResultSet1>
            <ns0:SharedID>SharedID_2</ns0:SharedID>
            <ns0:MiscInfoB1>B1_2</ns0:MiscInfoB1>
            <ns0:MiscInfoB2>B2_2</ns0:MiscInfoB2>
        </ns0:TypedPollingResultSet1>
    </ns0:TypedPollingResultSet1>

    <ns0:TypedPollingResultSet2>
        <ns0:TypedPollingResultSet2>
            <ns0:SharedID>SharedID_1</ns0:SharedID>
            <ns0:MiscInfoBA1>BA1_1A</ns0:MiscInfoBA1>
            <ns0:MiscInfoBA2>BA2_1A</ns0:MiscInfoBA2>
        </ns0:TypedPollingResultSet2>

        <ns0:TypedPollingResultSet2>
            <ns0:SharedID>SharedID_1</ns0:SharedID>
            <ns0:MiscInfoBA1>BA1_1B</ns0:MiscInfoBA1>
            <ns0:MiscInfoBA2>BA2_1B</ns0:MiscInfoBA2>
        </ns0:TypedPollingResultSet2>

        <ns0:TypedPollingResultSet2>
            <ns0:SharedID>SharedID_2</ns0:SharedID>
            <ns0:MiscInfoBA1>BA1_2A</ns0:MiscInfoBA1>
            <ns0:MiscInfoBA2>BA2_2A</ns0:MiscInfoBA2>
        </ns0:TypedPollingResultSet2>

        <ns0:TypedPollingResultSet2>
            <ns0:SharedID>SharedID_2</ns0:SharedID>
            <ns0:MiscInfoBA1>BA1_2B</ns0:MiscInfoBA1>
            <ns0:MiscInfoBA2>BA2_2B</ns0:MiscInfoBA2>
        </ns0:TypedPollingResultSet2>
    </ns0:TypedPollingResultSet2>

    <ns0:TypedPollingResultSet3>
        <ns0:TypedPollingResultSet3>
            <ns0:SharedID>SharedID_1</ns0:SharedID>
            <ns0:MiscInfoBB1>BB1_1A</ns0:MiscInfoBB1>
            <ns0:MiscInfoBB2>BB2_1A</ns0:MiscInfoBB2>
        </ns0:TypedPollingResultSet3>

        <ns0:TypedPollingResultSet3>
            <ns0:SharedID>SharedID_1</ns0:SharedID>
            <ns0:MiscInfoBB1>BB1_1B</ns0:MiscInfoBB1>
            <ns0:MiscInfoBB2>BB2_1B</ns0:MiscInfoBB2>
        </ns0:TypedPollingResultSet3>

        <ns0:TypedPollingResultSet3>
            <ns0:SharedID>SharedID_2</ns0:SharedID>
            <ns0:MiscInfoBB1>BB1_2</ns0:MiscInfoBB1>
            <ns0:MiscInfoBB2>BB2_2</ns0:MiscInfoBB2>
        </ns0:TypedPollingResultSet3>
    </ns0:TypedPollingResultSet3>

    <ns0:TypedPollingResultSet4>
        <ns0:TypedPollingResultSet4>
            <ns0:SharedID>SharedID_1</ns0:SharedID>
            <ns0:GroupCInstanceID>GroupCInstanceID_1A</ns0:GroupCInstanceID>
            <ns0:MiscInfoC1>C1_1A</ns0:MiscInfoC1>
            <ns0:MiscInfoC2>C2_1A</ns0:MiscInfoC2>
        </ns0:TypedPollingResultSet4>

        <ns0:TypedPollingResultSet4>
            <ns0:SharedID>SharedID_1</ns0:SharedID>
            <ns0:GroupCInstanceID>GroupCInstanceID_1B</ns0:GroupCInstanceID>
            <ns0:MiscInfoC1>C1_1B</ns0:MiscInfoC1>
            <ns0:MiscInfoC2>C2_1B</ns0:MiscInfoC2>
        </ns0:TypedPollingResultSet4>

        <ns0:TypedPollingResultSet4>
            <ns0:SharedID>SharedID_2</ns0:SharedID>
            <ns0:GroupCInstanceID>GroupCInstanceID_2</ns0:GroupCInstanceID>
            <ns0:MiscInfoC1>C1_2</ns0:MiscInfoC1>
            <ns0:MiscInfoC2>C2_2</ns0:MiscInfoC2>
        </ns0:TypedPollingResultSet4>
    </ns0:TypedPollingResultSet4>

    <ns0:TypedPollingResultSet5>
        <ns0:TypedPollingResultSet5>
            <ns0:SharedID>SharedID_1</ns0:SharedID>
            <ns0:GroupDInstanceID>GroupDInstanceID_1A</ns0:GroupDInstanceID>
            <ns0:MiscInfoD1>D1_1A</ns0:MiscInfoD1>
            <ns0:MiscInfoD2>D2_1A</ns0:MiscInfoD2>
        </ns0:TypedPollingResultSet5>

        <ns0:TypedPollingResultSet5>
            <ns0:SharedID>SharedID_1</ns0:SharedID>
            <ns0:GroupDInstanceID>GroupDInstanceID_1B</ns0:GroupDInstanceID>
            <ns0:MiscInfoD1>D1_1B</ns0:MiscInfoD1>
            <ns0:MiscInfoD2>D2_1B</ns0:MiscInfoD2>
        </ns0:TypedPollingResultSet5>

        <ns0:TypedPollingResultSet5>
            <ns0:SharedID>SharedID_2</ns0:SharedID>
            <ns0:GroupDInstanceID>GroupDInstanceID_2</ns0:GroupDInstanceID>
            <ns0:MiscInfoD1>D1_2</ns0:MiscInfoD1>
            <ns0:MiscInfoD2>D2_2</ns0:MiscInfoD2>
        </ns0:TypedPollingResultSet5>
    </ns0:TypedPollingResultSet5>

    <ns0:TypedPollingResultSet6>
        <ns0:TypedPollingResultSet6>
            <ns0:SharedID>SharedID_1</ns0:SharedID>
            <ns0:GroupDInstanceID>GroupDInstanceID_1A</ns0:GroupDInstanceID>
            <ns0:MiscInfoDA1>DA1_1A</ns0:MiscInfoDA1>
            <ns0:MiscInfoDA2>DA2_1A</ns0:MiscInfoDA2>
        </ns0:TypedPollingResultSet6>

        <ns0:TypedPollingResultSet6>
            <ns0:SharedID>SharedID_1</ns0:SharedID>
            <ns0:GroupDInstanceID>GroupDInstanceID_1B</ns0:GroupDInstanceID>
            <ns0:MiscInfoDA1>DA1_1B</ns0:MiscInfoDA1>
            <ns0:MiscInfoDA2>DA2_1B</ns0:MiscInfoDA2>
        </ns0:TypedPollingResultSet6>

        <ns0:TypedPollingResultSet6>
            <ns0:SharedID>SharedID_2</ns0:SharedID>
            <ns0:GroupDInstanceID>GroupDInstanceID_2</ns0:GroupDInstanceID>
            <ns0:MiscInfoDA1>DA1_2</ns0:MiscInfoDA1>
            <ns0:MiscInfoDA2>DA2_2</ns0:MiscInfoDA2>
        </ns0:TypedPollingResultSet6>
    </ns0:TypedPollingResultSet6>

    <ns0:TypedPollingResultSet7>
        <ns0:TypedPollingResultSet7>
            <ns0:SharedID>SharedID_1</ns0:SharedID>
            <ns0:GroupDInstanceID>GroupDInstanceID_1A</ns0:GroupDInstanceID>
            <ns0:MiscInfoDB1>DB1_1A</ns0:MiscInfoDB1>
            <ns0:MiscInfoDB2>DB2_1A</ns0:MiscInfoDB2>
        </ns0:TypedPollingResultSet7>

        <ns0:TypedPollingResultSet7>
            <ns0:SharedID>SharedID_1</ns0:SharedID>
            <ns0:GroupDInstanceID>GroupDInstanceID_1B</ns0:GroupDInstanceID>
            <ns0:MiscInfoDB1>DB1_1B</ns0:MiscInfoDB1>
            <ns0:MiscInfoDB2>DB2_1B</ns0:MiscInfoDB2>
        </ns0:TypedPollingResultSet7>

        <ns0:TypedPollingResultSet7>
            <ns0:SharedID>SharedID_2</ns0:SharedID>
            <ns0:GroupDInstanceID>GroupDInstanceID_2</ns0:GroupDInstanceID>
            <ns0:MiscInfoDB1>DB1_2</ns0:MiscInfoDB1>
            <ns0:MiscInfoDB2>DB2_2</ns0:MiscInfoDB2>
        </ns0:TypedPollingResultSet7>
    </ns0:TypedPollingResultSet7>
</ns0:TypedPolling>
```

Desired output:

```
<ns0:AllRecords xmlns:ns0="http://SmallGenericSchemaTest.Schemas/DestinationSchema">
    <ns0:SingleRecord>
        <ns0:GroupA>
            <ns0:SharedID>SharedID_1</ns0:SharedID>
            <ns0:MiscInfoA1>A1_1</ns0:MiscInfoA1>
            <ns0:MiscInfoA2>A2_1</ns0:MiscInfoA2>
        </ns0:GroupA>

        <ns0:GroupB>
            <ns0:MiscInfoB1>B1_1</ns0:MiscInfoB1>
            <ns0:MiscInfoB2>B2_1</ns0:MiscInfoB2>

            <ns0:SubGroupBAContainer>
                <ns0:SubGroupBA>
                    <ns0:MiscInfoBA1>BA1_1A</ns0:MiscInfoBA1>
                    <ns0:MiscInfoBA2>BA2_1A</ns0:MiscInfoBA2>
                </ns0:SubGroupBA>

                <ns0:SubGroupBA>
                    <ns0:MiscInfoBA1>BA1_1B</ns0:MiscInfoBA1>
                    <ns0:MiscInfoBA2>BA2_1B</ns0:MiscInfoBA2>
                </ns0:SubGroupBA>
            </ns0:SubGroupBAContainer>

            <ns0:SubGroupBBContainer>
                <ns0:SubGroupBB>
                    <ns0:MiscInfoBB1>BB1_1A</ns0:MiscInfoBB1>
                    <ns0:MiscInfoBB2>BB2_1A</ns0:MiscInfoBB2>
                </ns0:SubGroupBB>

                <ns0:SubGroupBB>
                    <ns0:MiscInfoBB1>BB1_1B</ns0:MiscInfoBB1>
                    <ns0:MiscInfoBB2>BB2_1B</ns0:MiscInfoBB2>
                </ns0:SubGroupBB>
            </ns0:SubGroupBBContainer>
        </ns0:GroupB>

        <ns0:GroupCContainer>
            <ns0:GroupC>
                <ns0:GroupCInstanceID>GroupCInstanceID_1A</ns0:GroupCInstanceID>
                <ns0:MiscInfoC1>C1_1A</ns0:MiscInfoC1>
                <ns0:MiscInfoC2>C2_1A</ns0:MiscInfoC2>
            </ns0:GroupC>

            <ns0:GroupC>
                <ns0:GroupCInstanceID>GroupCInstanceID_1B</ns0:GroupCInstanceID>
                <ns0:MiscInfoC1>C1_1B</ns0:MiscInfoC1>
                <ns0:MiscInfoC2>C2_1B</ns0:MiscInfoC2>
            </ns0:GroupC>
        </ns0:GroupCContainer>

        <ns0:GroupDContainer>
            <ns0:GroupD>
                <ns0:GroupDInstanceID>GroupDInstanceID_1A</ns0:GroupDInstanceID>
                <ns0:MiscInfoD1>D1_1A</ns0:MiscInfoD1>
                <ns0:MiscInfoD2>D2_1A</ns0:MiscInfoD2>

                <ns0:SubGroupDA>
                    <ns0:MiscInfoDA1>DA1_1A</ns0:MiscInfoDA1>
                    <ns0:MiscInfoDA2>DA2_1A</ns0:MiscInfoDA2>
                </ns0:SubGroupDA>

                <ns0:SubGroupDBContainer>
                    <ns0:SubGroupDB>
                        <ns0:MiscInfoDB1>DB1_1A</ns0:MiscInfoDB1>
                        <ns0:MiscInfoDB2>DB2_1A</ns0:MiscInfoDB2>
                    </ns0:SubGroupDB>
                </ns0:SubGroupDBContainer>
            </ns0:GroupD>

            <ns0:GroupD>
                <ns0:GroupDInstanceID>GroupDInstanceID_1B</ns0:GroupDInstanceID>
                <ns0:MiscInfoD1>D1_1B</ns0:MiscInfoD1>
                <ns0:MiscInfoD2>D2_1B</ns0:MiscInfoD2>

                <ns0:SubGroupDA>
                    <ns0:MiscInfoDA1>DA1_1B</ns0:MiscInfoDA1>
                    <ns0:MiscInfoDA2>DA2_1B</ns0:MiscInfoDA2>
                </ns0:SubGroupDA>

                <ns0:SubGroupDBContainer>
                    <ns0:SubGroupDB>
                        <ns0:MiscInfoDB1>DB1_1B</ns0:MiscInfoDB1>
                        <ns0:MiscInfoDB2>DB2_1B</ns0:MiscInfoDB2>
                    </ns0:SubGroupDB>
                </ns0:SubGroupDBContainer>
            </ns0:GroupD>
        </ns0:GroupDContainer>
    </ns0:SingleRecord>

    <ns0:SingleRecord>
        <ns0:GroupA>
            <ns0:SharedID>SharedID_2</ns0:SharedID>
            <ns0:MiscInfoA1>A1_2</ns0:MiscInfoA1>
            <ns0:MiscInfoA2>A2_2</ns0:MiscInfoA2>
        </ns0:GroupA>

        <ns0:GroupB>
            <ns0:MiscInfoB1>B1_2</ns0:MiscInfoB1>
            <ns0:MiscInfoB2>B2_2</ns0:MiscInfoB2>

            <ns0:SubGroupBAContainer>
                <ns0:SubGroupBA>
                    <ns0:MiscInfoBA1>BA1_2A</ns0:MiscInfoBA1>
                    <ns0:MiscInfoBA2>BA2_2A</ns0:MiscInfoBA2>
                </ns0:SubGroupBA>

                <ns0:SubGroupBA>
                    <ns0:MiscInfoBA1>BA1_2B</ns0:MiscInfoBA1>
                    <ns0:MiscInfoBA2>BA2_2B</ns0:MiscInfoBA2>
                </ns0:SubGroupBA>
            </ns0:SubGroupBAContainer>

            <ns0:SubGroupBBContainer>
                <ns0:SubGroupBB>
                    <ns0:MiscInfoBB1>BB1_2</ns0:MiscInfoBB1>
                    <ns0:MiscInfoBB2>BB2_2</ns0:MiscInfoBB2>
                </ns0:SubGroupBB>
            </ns0:SubGroupBBContainer>
        </ns0:GroupB>

        <ns0:GroupCContainer>
            <ns0:GroupC>
                <ns0:GroupCInstanceID>GroupCInstanceID_2</ns0:GroupCInstanceID>
                <ns0:MiscInfoC1>C1_2</ns0:MiscInfoC1>
                <ns0:MiscInfoC2>C2_2</ns0:MiscInfoC2>
            </ns0:GroupC>
        </ns0:GroupCContainer>

        <ns0:GroupDContainer>
            <ns0:GroupD>
                <ns0:GroupDInstanceID>GroupDInstanceID_2</ns0:GroupDInstanceID>
                <ns0:MiscInfoD1>D1_2</ns0:MiscInfoD1>
                <ns0:MiscInfoD2>D2_2</ns0:MiscInfoD2>

                <ns0:SubGroupDA>
                    <ns0:MiscInfoDA1>DA1_2</ns0:MiscInfoDA1>
                    <ns0:MiscInfoDA2>DA2_2</ns0:MiscInfoDA2>
                </ns0:SubGroupDA>

                <ns0:SubGroupDBContainer>
                    <ns0:SubGroupDB>
                        <ns0:MiscInfoDB1>DB1_2</ns0:MiscInfoDB1>
                        <ns0:MiscInfoDB2>DB2_2</ns0:MiscInfoDB2>
                    </ns0:SubGroupDB>
                </ns0:SubGroupDBContainer>
            </ns0:GroupD>
        </ns0:GroupDContainer>
    </ns0:SingleRecord>
</ns0:AllRecords>
```

Comment: Without a sample payload it is a bit hard for people to reproduce.  Can you add that?  Also highlighting what the current output is vs what you want would also help.

Comment: Did you try a FOR XML query?  In that case, SQL Server will talk care of all the grouping for you.

Comment: Actually, very important, this may *not* be a Muenchian case.  Is SharedID in TypedPollingResultSet0 unique per resultset?  If so, this is not a Muenchian case and gets a lot easier.

Comment: Dijkgraaf, that's a good point. I added a sample input and the desired output.

Comment: Johns-305, we have used FOR XML in the past, but the scripts end up being a few thousand lines of generating XML manually. I am avoiding that in hopes of finding a better way, which led me to this approach. As for the question on SharedID in TypedPollingResultSet0, yes it is unique per resultset. Are you saying I should be able to just use for-each elements without dealing with assigning keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Johns-305's suggestion, I looked at alternatives to Muenchian grouping and arrived at the solution below which appears to be working as intended. It certainly seems that I had given myself tunnel vision after looking into the Muenchian method. The end result did end up being a lot easier, but my inexperience with XSLT made it less obvious.

Of course, if someone knows of a better way to do this or sees any room for improvement, please feel free to make additional suggestions. I'll keep the question open for a few days before accepting this answer in case a better one comes along. Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var s0"
                version="1.0"
                xmlns:s0="http://SmallGenericSchemaTest.Schemas/SourceSchema"
                xmlns:ns0="http://SmallGenericSchemaTest.Schemas/DestinationSchema">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/s0:TypedPolling" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/s0:TypedPolling">
        <ns0:AllRecords>
            <xsl:for-each select="s0:TypedPollingResultSet0/s0:TypedPollingResultSet0">
                <ns0:SingleRecord>

                    <ns0:GroupA>
                        <xsl:if test="s0:SharedID">
                            <ns0:SharedID>
                                <xsl:value-of select="s0:SharedID/text()" />
                            </ns0:SharedID>
                        </xsl:if>

                        <xsl:if test="s0:MiscInfoA1">
                            <ns0:MiscInfoA1>
                                <xsl:value-of select="s0:MiscInfoA1/text()" />
                            </ns0:MiscInfoA1>
                        </xsl:if>

                        <xsl:if test="s0:MiscInfoA2">
                            <ns0:MiscInfoA2>
                                <xsl:value-of select="s0:MiscInfoA2/text()" />
                            </ns0:MiscInfoA2>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </ns0:GroupA>


                    <xsl:for-each select="/s0:TypedPolling/s0:TypedPollingResultSet1/s0:TypedPollingResultSet1[s0:SharedID = current()/s0:SharedID]">
                        <ns0:GroupB>
                            <xsl:if test="s0:MiscInfoB1">
                                <ns0:MiscInfoB1>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="s0:MiscInfoB1/text()" />
                                </ns0:MiscInfoB1>
                            </xsl:if>

                            <xsl:if test="s0:MiscInfoB2">
                                <ns0:MiscInfoB2>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="s0:MiscInfoB2/text()" />
                                </ns0:MiscInfoB2>
                            </xsl:if>

                            <ns0:SubGroupBAContainer>
                                <xsl:for-each select="/s0:TypedPolling/s0:TypedPollingResultSet2/s0:TypedPollingResultSet2[s0:SharedID = current()/s0:SharedID]">
                                    <ns0:SubGroupBA>
                                        <xsl:if test="s0:MiscInfoBA1">
                                            <ns0:MiscInfoBA1>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="s0:MiscInfoBA1/text()" />
                                            </ns0:MiscInfoBA1>
                                        </xsl:if>

                                        <xsl:if test="s0:MiscInfoBA2">
                                            <ns0:MiscInfoBA2>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="s0:MiscInfoBA2/text()" />
                                            </ns0:MiscInfoBA2>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                    </ns0:SubGroupBA>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </ns0:SubGroupBAContainer>

                            <ns0:SubGroupBBContainer>
                                <xsl:for-each select="/s0:TypedPolling/s0:TypedPollingResultSet3/s0:TypedPollingResultSet3[s0:SharedID = current()/s0:SharedID]">
                                    <ns0:SubGroupBB>
                                        <xsl:if test="s0:MiscInfoBB1">
                                            <ns0:MiscInfoBB1>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="s0:MiscInfoBB1/text()" />
                                            </ns0:MiscInfoBB1>
                                        </xsl:if>

                                        <xsl:if test="s0:MiscInfoBB2">
                                            <ns0:MiscInfoBB2>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="s0:MiscInfoBB2/text()" />
                                            </ns0:MiscInfoBB2>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                    </ns0:SubGroupBB>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </ns0:SubGroupBBContainer>
                        </ns0:GroupB>
                    </xsl:for-each>


                    <xsl:if test="/s0:TypedPolling/s0:TypedPollingResultSet4/s0:TypedPollingResultSet4[s0:SharedID = current()/s0:SharedID]">
                        <ns0:GroupCContainer>
                            <xsl:for-each select="/s0:TypedPolling/s0:TypedPollingResultSet4/s0:TypedPollingResultSet4[s0:SharedID = current()/s0:SharedID]">
                                <ns0:GroupC>
                                    <xsl:if test="s0:GroupCInstanceID">
                                        <ns0:GroupCInstanceID>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="s0:GroupCInstanceID/text()" />
                                        </ns0:GroupCInstanceID>
                                    </xsl:if>

                                    <xsl:if test="s0:MiscInfoC1">
                                        <ns0:MiscInfoC1>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="s0:MiscInfoC1/text()" />
                                        </ns0:MiscInfoC1>
                                    </xsl:if>

                                    <xsl:if test="s0:MiscInfoC2">
                                        <ns0:MiscInfoC2>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="s0:MiscInfoC2/text()" />
                                        </ns0:MiscInfoC2>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                </ns0:GroupC>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </ns0:GroupCContainer>
                    </xsl:if>


                    <xsl:if test="/s0:TypedPolling/s0:TypedPollingResultSet5/s0:TypedPollingResultSet5[s0:SharedID = current()/s0:SharedID]">
                        <ns0:GroupDContainer>
                            <xsl:for-each select="/s0:TypedPolling/s0:TypedPollingResultSet5/s0:TypedPollingResultSet5[s0:SharedID = current()/s0:SharedID]">
                                <ns0:GroupD>
                                    <xsl:if test="s0:GroupDInstanceID">
                                        <ns0:GroupDInstanceID>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="s0:GroupDInstanceID/text()" />
                                        </ns0:GroupDInstanceID>
                                    </xsl:if>

                                    <xsl:if test="s0:MiscInfoD1">
                                        <ns0:MiscInfoD1>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="s0:MiscInfoD1/text()" />
                                        </ns0:MiscInfoD1>
                                    </xsl:if>

                                    <xsl:if test="s0:MiscInfoD2">
                                        <ns0:MiscInfoD2>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="s0:MiscInfoD2/text()" />
                                        </ns0:MiscInfoD2>
                                    </xsl:if>

                                    <xsl:if test="/s0:TypedPolling/s0:TypedPollingResultSet6/s0:TypedPollingResultSet6[s0:SharedID = current()/s0:SharedID]
                                            and /s0:TypedPolling/s0:TypedPollingResultSet6/s0:TypedPollingResultSet6[s0:GroupDInstanceID = current()/s0:GroupDInstanceID]">
                                        <xsl:for-each select="/s0:TypedPolling/s0:TypedPollingResultSet6/s0:TypedPollingResultSet6[s0:SharedID = current()/s0:SharedID
                                                      and s0:GroupDInstanceID = current()/s0:GroupDInstanceID]">
                                            <ns0:SubGroupDA>
                                                <xsl:if test="s0:MiscInfoDA1">
                                                    <ns0:MiscInfoDA1>
                                                        <xsl:value-of select="s0:MiscInfoDA1/text()" />
                                                    </ns0:MiscInfoDA1>
                                                </xsl:if>

                                                <xsl:if test="s0:MiscInfoDA2">
                                                    <ns0:MiscInfoDA2>
                                                        <xsl:value-of select="s0:MiscInfoDA2/text()" />
                                                    </ns0:MiscInfoDA2>
                                                </xsl:if>
                                            </ns0:SubGroupDA>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                    </xsl:if>

                                    <xsl:if test="/s0:TypedPolling/s0:TypedPollingResultSet7/s0:TypedPollingResultSet7[s0:SharedID = current()/s0:SharedID]
                                            and /s0:TypedPolling/s0:TypedPollingResultSet7/s0:TypedPollingResultSet7[s0:GroupDInstanceID = current()/s0:GroupDInstanceID]">
                                        <ns0:SubGroupDBContainer>
                                            <xsl:for-each select="/s0:TypedPolling/s0:TypedPollingResultSet7/s0:TypedPollingResultSet7[s0:SharedID = current()/s0:SharedID
                                                          and s0:GroupDInstanceID = current()/s0:GroupDInstanceID]">
                                                <ns0:SubGroupDB>
                                                    <xsl:if test="s0:MiscInfoDB1">
                                                        <ns0:MiscInfoDB1>
                                                            <xsl:value-of select="s0:MiscInfoDB1/text()" />
                                                        </ns0:MiscInfoDB1>
                                                    </xsl:if>

                                                    <xsl:if test="s0:MiscInfoDB2">
                                                        <ns0:MiscInfoDB2>
                                                            <xsl:value-of select="s0:MiscInfoDB2/text()" />
                                                        </ns0:MiscInfoDB2>
                                                    </xsl:if>
                                                </ns0:SubGroupDB>
                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                        </ns0:SubGroupDBContainer>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                </ns0:GroupD>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </ns0:GroupDContainer>
                    </xsl:if>

                </ns0:SingleRecord>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ns0:AllRecords>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```